# css - Revert select to normal state when mouse is out

Tags: html, css

HTML Code:

```
<select id="dict">
<option value="1">Google.com</option>
<option value="2">TheFreeDictionary.com</option>
<option value="3">Dictionary.Reference.com</option>
<option value="4">Merriam-Webster.com</option>
<option value="5">MacmillanDictionary.com</option>
<option value="6">OxfordDictionaries.com</option>
<option value="7">CollinsDictionary.com</option>
</select>
```

CSS Code:

```
#dict {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #646464;
    padding-left: 1.5px;
    padding-right: 1.5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-width: thin;
    width: 263.5px; 
}

#dict:hover {
    border-color: #06F;
    color: #06F;
}

#dict:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #093;
    color: #093;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzf9Z/). This creates a `select` dropdownlist with rounded corners.

The problem now is that, when you click on the dropdownlist (and the options will appear) and then you click it again (get the options to disappear) and then you move your mouse away from the dropdownlist, the color of the text and the border of the dropdownlist is still green.

How do I fix it?

---

Also, I realised that when the dropdownlist is clicked, the `select` turns green, but the options turn green too. How do I make the options not change colour when the dropdownlist is clicked?

---

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:** Also, how do I make it such that the text of the selected option appears red?

Comment: i checked that on fiddle even your fiddle is nt showing me your first problem

Comment: when u want it green ? in list or in select without mouse over or clicked ?

Comment: check my edit i edited it with your new Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in your css

```
option {
        color:#000000;


}
```

EDIT

i never did this but i guess it can achieve like this

```
option[selected=selected]{
    color:red;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved the second problem, but unfortunately not the first one.

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit? I have another question

Comment: it will only work when your any option has selected="selected"

Answer (score 1):

this should solve

```
  #dict {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #646464;
    padding-left: 1.5px;
    padding-right: 1.5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-width: thin;
    width: 263.5px;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
#dict option {
    color:#000000;
}

#dict:focus {
    border-color: #093;
    color: #093;
}
#dict:hover {
    border-color: #06F;
    color: #06F;
}
```

Comment: user doesnt want to change color of options when select is clicked it is changing color

Comment: Now when the dropdownlist is clicked, it will be blue when you put your mouse over it. Not what I want. Also, the first problem still persists. In fact, both problems still persist...